# How to reads .crt file in Android

Tags: android

I write following code to implement reading .crt file, but it doesn't work.

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

InputStream in = null;

in = assetManager.open("client.crt");

CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(in);
```

The last line doesn't execute. Somebody please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code snippet

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    // From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
    InputStream is = context.getResources().getAssets().openAsset("somefolder/somecertificate.crt"); // path should be your files path
    InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    Certificate ca;
    try {
        ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        // System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
    } finally {
        caInput.close();
    }
```

Comment: No. I find android has some problem reading .crt file by losing some content.